# Button hover does not work after I change button color using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button that has a color change when hovering. And in Script the button color changes when a click event occurs.  However, Hover works when the page is loaded but after the color changes, it doesn't work. The code is below:

```js
var count = 1;

function setColor(btn, color) {
  var property = document.getElementById(btn);
  if (count == 0) {
    property.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    count = 1;
  } else {
    property.style.backgroundColor = color;
    count = 0;
  }
}
```

```css
.button {
  background-color: #4caf50;
  /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button1 {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #4caf50;
}

.button1:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #4caf50;
}
```

```html
<h2> Hoverable Buttons</h2>
<button id="buttonGreen" class="button button1" onclick="setColor('buttonGreen', '#122256')">
Green</button>
```

After I click the button event occurs and the color changes to dark blue and the hover do not work.

Comment: Is the idea that the initial colour is green, and then it toggles between white and blue when you click on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

button click adds inline styles which have higher priority due to that hover property changes are ignored. You can add `!important` to get rid of the issue

```
.button1:hover {
     background-color: red !important;
     color: black !important;
     border: 2px solid #4caf50;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .button {
        background-color: #4caf50; /* Green */
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 16px 32px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin: 4px 2px;
        transition-duration: 0.4s;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      .button1 {
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
        border: 2px solid #4caf50;
      }

      .button1:hover {
        background-color: red !important;
        color: black !important;
        border: 2px solid #4caf50;
      }
    </style>

    <script>
      var count = 1;
      function setColor(btn, color) {
        var property = document.getElementById(btn);
        if (count == 0) {
          property.style.backgroundColor = "white";
          count = 1;
        } else {
          property.style.backgroundColor = color;
          count = 0;
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h2>Hoverable Buttons</h2>
    <button
      id="buttonGreen"
      class="button button1"
      onclick="setColor('buttonGreen', '#122256')"
      ;
    >
      Green
    </button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Asif Hussain, check this out !!

Answer (score 1):

**Inline styling (applied via `style` attribute) takes precedence over CSS applied styling (applied via `class` attribute).**

Before click there was no `background-color` defined via `style`, after click there is which is overruling your CSS `.button1:hover` `background-color`. See [documentation on CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) for more details on this topic.

---

To see the hover effect after clicking the button, try updating your `.button1:hover` to the following:

```css
.button1:hover {
  background-color: red !important;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #4caf50;
}
```

**Note** the use of `!important` which instructs the browser to give precedence over the inline styling.

⚠️ Using `!important` is generally not good practice therefore don't consider this to be a solution rather a topic to look into.

Answer (score 0):

That occurs because you set background style white. Change this line in your condition. I would remove style elememnt. But you can set transparent background. What you are like!

```js
if (count == 0) {
   // property.style.backgroundColor = "white";
   property.removeAttribute('style');
  ...
```

**Working example**

```js
      var count = 1;
      function setColor(btn, color) {
        var property = document.getElementById(btn);
        if (count == 0) {          
          property.removeAttribute('style');
          count = 1;
        } else {
          
          property.style.backgroundColor = color;
          count = 0;
        }
      }
```

```css
      .button {
        background-color: #4caf50; /* Green */
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 16px 32px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin: 4px 2px;
        transition-duration: 0.4s;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      .button1 {
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
        border: 2px solid #4caf50;
      }

      .button1:hover {
        background-color: red;
        color: black;
        border: 2px solid #4caf50;
      }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>

    </style>

    <script>

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h2>Hoverable Buttons</h2>
    <button
      id="buttonGreen"
      class="button button1"
      onclick="setColor('buttonGreen', '#122256')"
      ;
    >
      Green1
    </button>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Note** But better to use classes and then js toggle function.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably avoid inline JS. Here's an example that uses a closure to prevent globals variables, and some modified CSS so you don't have to add styles directly on to the element. Think more of the `button`, and how it changes. You basically adding and removing colours, so make them the new CSS classes.

```js
// Cache the button
const button = document.querySelector('button');

// Add an event handler to it. The handler is a function
// that returns another function which acts as the listener
// This way you don't need to create global variables.
// A function that's returned from another function, and carries
// with it the variables from its local lexical environment
// is called a closure.
button.addEventListener('click', setColor(), false);

function setColor(color) {
  
  // Initialise count
  let count = true;
  
  // Return the function to be used as the button
  // handler. Instead of updating the style directly
  // just simply add/remove classes to the element
  return function () {
    this.classList.remove('green');
    if (count) {
      this.classList.remove('blue');
      this.classList.add('white');
      this.textContent = 'White';
    } else {
      this.classList.add('blue');
      this.classList.remove('white');
      this.textContent = 'Blue';
    }

    // Change count to true if it's false, or
    // false if it's true
    count = !count;
  }

}
```

```css
.button {
  border: 2px solid #4caf50;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.white { background-color: white; }
.green { background-color: #4caf50; }
.blue { background-color: #122256; color: white; }
```

```html
<h2>Hoverable Buttons</h2>
<button class="button green">Green</button>
```